# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Tengo un textarea que se rellena con datos de mysql usando .val()

Resulta que al escribir saltos de linea o espacios en ese textarea me devuelve el `error SyntaxError: unterminated string literal.`

por lo que leo [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal)  es porque tengo que escapar el texto cerrando comillas y poniendo un + pero claro no puedo hacerlo ya que es un campo dinámico y si le digo al usuario que tiene que poner los + en cada linea se que no lo va a hacer y me va a hacer destrozos en la web.

¿hay alguna forma de escapar de eso?

he probado usando `str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $str);` y no da el error, pero no hace los saltos de linea y los necesito :(

y si pongo `preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br />',$str);` me cambia los espacios por `<br/>` pero al ponerse en el textarea no los interpreta como html y los escribe literalmente.

Comment: No estoy seguro si entendí bien lo siguiente: `escapar el texto cerrando comillas y poniendo un +` ¿podrías por favor actualizar tu pregunta colocando el fragmento de código que procesa el texto del textarea? Quisiera saber cómo estás haciendo la inserción de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final solo tenia que cambiar `<br />` por \n y ya funciona.

Ha quedado así `preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'\n',$str);`y todo OK